# Showing "lighthouse is warming up" forever

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I built my first **Progressive Web App** (PWA) in react js. When I click on **Generate report** on Chrome's Audit tab in DevTools, it is showing the message *lighthouse is warming up* forever.

My chrome version is 81.

What can i do to generate report?

Comment: What are you running a Lighthouse audit on?

Comment: chrome developer tools

Comment: No, I meant, what are you auditing?

Comment: my personal react app

Comment: Is it already built and running in the browser?

Comment: yes, it is running

Comment: You are using an IP which is blocked by Google like Iranian IP. Try to use a VPN and then generate the report.

Comment: Did you look for errors in the console? Does it work ok on this sample site? https://airhorner.com/

Comment: You may also want to try adding the extension and not use the version built into the dev tools.

Comment: For me local pages work with built-in Lighthouse, and online counterparts with the browser extension (can be just a coincidence though ‍♂️)

Comment: Related GitHub issue for this problem in Chrome v112: ["Lighthouse is warming up..." in Chrome M112 #15026](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/15026); TL;DR: restart Chrome once and try again.

Comment: Three years later and this is still an issue. Ugh

Answer (score 23):

I solve this problem by kill Chrome then open it again

Answer (score 20):

One of the fastest solutions is typing this in the URL:

```
chrome://restart
```

Comment: Why didn't I know this?!?!?! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

it worked for me when I ran lighthouse audit for the same site on an **Incognito Window**

Comment: O thanks u boss.. :) Did not think to even try, it works great.

Comment: I'm having the issue even on Incognito tab

Comment: @quickshiftin hi i'm sorry this didnt solve the issue. i have no explanation for why this worked in the first place either. this was some time back and probably a bug that was fixed. maybe some other answer here helps

Comment: no problem, I'm just noting the issue can occur on an incognito tab

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was solved just by updating Chrome browser.

Comment: it solved my issue too, I was using v96+ but updating to the latest version has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable these two options from chrome settings:

- Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed
- Use hardware acceleration when available

Relaunch chrome then try again

That works for me

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue. We once ran the lighthouse for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), to check its functionality, and then we lighthoused our sites. It audited the site and generated the report.

If you still face the same issue, start interacting with the site while lighthouse audits, this solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have solution for this issue, please follow below steps...

1. Open Task Manager (ctrl + alt + del)
2. Select Google Chrome
3. Click on "END TASK" button
4. Reopen Google chrome and check lighthouse

It's work for me every time :) ------
I hope it's work for you !!!